# Facebook "more from related pages" feature

Tags: applications, facebook

Recent updates on the Facebook app came with a new feature : "the more from related pages" after every time you like a post. For me this feature is terrible. Every time after I liked a post I would scroll down to like another one, and just right before I hit the like button this new function will pop some icons out, pushing the wall down and cause me to miss the like button.

So here is the question: are there ways to remove this feature ? I searched through the settings on my app one by one but I have yet to find anything that works.

[Feature](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1auoaxoaA_CVg1ZAMwn8PFAourAvAkRviRQ/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: This is a Q&A site, and therefore is not suited for propaganda, hence I vote to close this question.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I actually would be really interested in fixing these problems regarding user interface. I don't mind the question being closed but I still would like to know how to disable Facebook recommending posts on my page. I am very sorry to the community that this sounded like a propaganda.

Comment: See, since the Facebook app is proprietary, no one but Facebook can change its code, and F has long been known for not caring about its uaers. All I can suggest, is to try some alternative Facebook clients, namely **Tinfoil for Facebook** or **Metal for Facebook** (*I'm not affiliated with the mentioned apps*). Aside from that, you're welcome to ask more questions in the future, but you might want to pay a look at the allowed topics.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman thanks a lot for these information. I was actually thinking whether I could in some way modify the Facebook app or the setting for this feature is not available on the mobile app. I'll be careful on my questions next time.

Comment: You *could* be able to modify the Facebook client, but you'll have to do so in a programming language which is neither friendly nor simple (and not exactly legal, but who cares).

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman well believe it or not, the feature disappeared. Maybe Facebook heard my voice. Now gonna delete this post.

Comment: Happy for you, then! Have a good day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem just.....disappeared